# How to make header sticky in ngx-datatable?

Tags: ngx-datatable

I want the table cound stick the header line when scrolling,how to make it possible?

I will be appreciate for your answer.

Comment: Hello, did you already try writing some code? Please have a look at the [posts guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: ngx-datatable already has the sticky header. Refer https://swimlane.github.io/ngx-datatable/#virtual-paging

Comment: but that is realy hard to use,since my table retrive data by http request in every  page.

Answer (score 0):

To make header sticky in ngx datatable just go to node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/themes/bootstrap.scss

In bootstrap.scss update the code to this

```css
.ngx-datatable.bootstrap {
  box-shadow: none;
  font-size: 13px;
  .datatable-header {
    height: unset !important;
    position: sticky;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 100;
    .datatable-header-cell {
      vertical-align: bottom;
      padding: 0.75rem;
      background: #383a3e;
      color: white;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #d1d4d7;
      .datatable-header-cell-label {
        line-height: 24px;
      }
    }
  }
```

Save the file and serve the project again to view the changes.